# Laravel Kernel middlewareGroups works for routes but not for grouped routes

Tags: php, laravel, cors, laravel-5.4

Sorry for the weird title. I'm not a native speaker.
So, here is my `routes/api.php` content:

```
Route::post('login', 'Api\LoginController@login');

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'restricted',
    'middleware' => 'auth:api',
], function () {
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::post('logout', 'Api\LoginController@logout');

    Route::get('user', 'Api\LoginController@getUser');
});
```

And as you probably know, every route inside this file has the `api` prefix by default. In my `Kernel.php` I've set a middleware for `api` routes:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        ...,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

Now my problem is that when i hit the `myapp/api/login` from a seprated app (angular.js app) it works fine but when i try to fetch user data from `myapp/api/restricted/user` i get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from `getUser` method on `Api\Login Controller`. I don't know why that trowed a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error but i'm happy it's fixed.